# jboss 7 logger write the same data to two different files

Tags: java, logging, jboss7.x

I have jboss 7.1.1 with the following definition:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <size-rotating-file-handler name="ACEII">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%z{utc}%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="ACEII.log"/>
            <rotate-size value="100K"/>
            <max-backup-index value="10"/>
            <append value="false"/>
        </size-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="ace2">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="ACEII"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
    </subsystem>
```

as u can see I have one handler that write to the server.log and the other to ACE2.log. problem is that the ACE2 logs are also written to the server.log, what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer, just add the use-parent-handlers="false" to your logger:

```
<logger category="ace2" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="ACEII"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `FILE` handler which writes to `server.log` is listed in the root logger and thus will receive the messages from the `ace2` logger as well.

Comment: So what you are saying is that every handler that is listed in the root logger will receive data from all other handlers?

Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: log4j has an additivity attribute which prevents this from happening, does Jboss7 logging has something similar?

Comment: @ftom2 I'm not sure about JBoss 7 logging but you might use log4j in your application. According to the JBoss 7 docs you should be able to plug log4j into the framework.